# How can I install unsupported converters for iconv AIX?

Tags: utf-8, aix, iconv, ebcdic, libiconv

I would like to install the appropriate converters so I could use iconv to convert EBCDIC Traditional chinese HKSCS to UTF-8 Traditional chinese HKSCS.

Can I install the converters locally in AIX?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [IBM docs](https://www.ibm.com/software/globalization/cp/cp_cpgid.html), "EBCDIC Traditional chinese" can refer to one of the code pages 835, 1043, 1159, 1376. When you say "EBCDIC Traditional chinese HKSCS", you probably mean [code page 1376](https://www.ibm.com/software/globalization/cp/cp01376.html).

AIX iconv supports code page 835, but not 1376. You could try this one and see if it produces satisfactory results.

The GNU libiconv implementation and ICU do not support these encodings.